# Problema con fechas en moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

tengo la siguiente duda.
Tengo un timestamp con valor

```
1565816027
```

Usando esta pagina

```
https://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=5&timestamp=1565816027&Submit=++++++Convert+to+Date++++++
```

Puedo saber que la fecha es:

```
14 de agosto de 2019
```

El problema es que si pongo

```
moment(1565816027).format();
```

Esto me da otra fecha.

```
1970-01-18T20:56:56-06:00
```

Alguien podría ayudarme para saber que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: la fecha que tiene está en segundos, y moment.format() supongo que maneja milisegundos, haz la prueba, en javascript coloca new Date().getTime(), y compara la cantidad de digitos con tu timestamp 1565816027

Comment: Oye si, puede ser eso. No lo había pensado uwu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debe verificar si se encuentra en Segundos o Milisegundos.

- `Segundos` si el tiempo tiene `10 cifras`
- `Milisegundos` si el tiempo
  tiene `13 cifras`

Para pasar de `Segundos` a  `Milisegundos` multiplicas el valor de segundos por `1.000`.

```js
let tiempo_segundos = 1565816027

let tiempo_milisegundos =  tiempo_segundos * 1000


// new Date(time milisegundos)
let fecha = new Date(tiempo_milisegundos)

console.log(fecha)
```

Comment: Gracias, ese era el problema.